# Трансляция веб-камеры в VLC на виртуальную машину

Tags: vmware, виртуальная-машина, камера, vlc, трансляция

Необходимо организовать трансляцию с камеры ноутбука на виртуальную машину (в vmware создал машину, организовал локальную сеть host-only, сеть работает, компьютеры пингуются и с хоста - Windows 10 и с гостевой ОС - Windows 8), в качестве средства трансляции использовал проект vlc для MSVS (т.к. далее буду модифицировать плеер) - [GitHub](https://github.com/sunqueen/vlc-2.2.1.32-2013). Трансляцию организую так:

> Передавать -> Устройство захвата -> в качестве видеоустройства выбираю
> web-камеру ноутбука -> поток -> Http, добавить -> порт 8080, путь - /
> -> включить перекодирование -> строка вывода *":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=автоматически,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=:8080/} :sout-keep"*
> -> поток.

В результате, при попытке открыть url хоста в гостевой ОС в том же vlc, он некоторое время пытается загрузить трансляцию, после чего никакой трансляции нет.
При попытке воспроизвести видео локально, на хосте воспроизводится только 1 кадр видео (т.е. трансляция застывает).
Пробовал использовать не проект vlc для MSVS c github, а саму программу (версии 2.2.2) - результат тот же. Сталкивался ли кто-нибудь с подобной проблемой?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Помогло следующее:
1) Добавил ip-адрес хоста в переменную "dst" в строке состояния

> ":sout=#transcode{vcodec=h264,scale=автоматически,acodec=mpga,ab=128,channels=2,samplerate=44100}:http{mux=ffmpeg{mux=flv},dst=**192.168.0.1**:8080}
>   :sout-keep"

2) Отключил файрвол NOD32